# How can I validate input to accept only binary numbers?

Tags: python

How can I validate some binary input to make sure that there are only 1s and 0s, not letters or other integers?

```
user_bin = (input('\nPlease enter binary number: '))

user_bin_list = list(user_bin)

while int(user_bin) < 0 or int(user_bin) > 1:
    print('Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.')
    user_bin = (input('\nPlease enter binary number: '))
```

So far I can only get my function to not accept integers other then 1 or 0 but it wont let me enter 1 and 0 combined.

The entire code:

```
#Prompt for and read user binary input
user_bin = list(input('\nPlease enter binary number: '))

user_bin_list = list(user_bin)
user_bin_len = len(user_bin_list)
powers_count = len(user_bin) - 1

index = 0
decimal_num = 0

while powers_count >= 0:
    decimal_num += (int(user_bin[index]))*(2**(powers_count))
    index += 1
    powers_count -= 1
print('\nDecimal number: ',decimal_num)
```

Comment: That's because you're parsing the input as a whole number, and since 10 > 1, it re-prompts you to enter a new number.

Comment: Note that the code I have suggested makes `user_bin` **an integer**, based on the user's binary input. There's no need to *"manually"* convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the easiest way to validate a user's input is to:

1. Treat it as if it *is* what you expect; and
2. Handle any errors if it *isn't*.

This is in line with Python's [*"easier to ask forgiveness than permission"*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) style. In this case, you're expecting an input you can interpret as binary:

```
while True:
    try:
        user_bin = int(input('\nPlease enter binary number: '), 2)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: @rks code is unreadable in comments, Python doubly so. If you have a new question, please ask it with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [second parameter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#int) (base) of the `int` constructor:

```
while True:
    user_bin_inp = raw_input('\nPlease enter a binary number: ')
    try:
        user_bin = int(user_bin_inp, 2)
    except ValueError:
        print("{!r} is not a valid binary integer.".format(user_bin_inp))
        continue
    break
```

Comment: It's a matter of taste.

Comment: Why do you need decimal conversion code? Just print out `user_bin`.